# Angular-Cli gitpages deploy deletes master and creates local of gh-pages branch

Tags: git, angular, github, angular-cli

I followed http://developer.telerik.com/featured/quick-angular-2-hosting-angular-cli-github-pages/

I was able to utilize the github-pages and view it great on github using:

ng github-pages:deploy

But each time I run this, it deletes my development local copy of the master branch and then replaces it with the production version.  Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?